# Переключатель контента на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Приветствую.
Совсем недавно познакомился с JS и вот недавно потребовалось написать небольшой скрипт для переключения контента. В принципе всё работает, но не совсем так как нужно. Сейчас есть три блока и у каждого блока несколько кнопок(переключателей), но у меня они зависят друг от друга, то есть если я хочу посмотреть контент второго блока, то из первого он пропадает. Соответственно прошу помощи: как заставить их работать по блокам, а не все вместе?

Код:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    var $links, $switcher;
    $links = $('[data-show]');
    $switcher = $('.switch-js');
    $switcher.children().not(':first').hide();
    $links.click(function() {
        var id;
        id = '[data-switch="' + $(this).data('show') + '"]';
        $switcher.children(id).show();
        $switcher.children().not(id).hide();
    });
});
jQuery(function($) {
    var $links2, $switcher2;
    $links2 = $('[data-show]');
    $switcher2 = $('.switch-js-2');
    $switcher2.children().not(':first').hide();
    $links2.click(function() {
        var id;
        id = '[data-switch="' + $(this).data('show') + '"]';
        $switcher2.children(id).show();
        $switcher2.children().not(id).hide();
    });
});
jQuery(function($) {
    var $links3, $switcher3;
    $links3 = $('[data-show]');
    $switcher3 = $('.switch-js-3');
    $switcher3.children().not(':first').hide();
    $links3.click(function() {
        var id;
        id = '[data-switch="' + $(this).data('show') + '"]';
        $switcher3.children(id).show();
        $switcher3.children().not(id).hide();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.switcher li').on('click', changeClass);
    $('.switcher-two li').on('click', changeClass2);
    $('.switcher-three li').on('click', changeClass3);
});
function changeClass() {
    $('.switcher li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
function changeClass2() {
    $('.switcher-two li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
function changeClass3() {
    $('.switcher-three li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.decorated {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.decorated__type2 {
    background: #fbf9f7;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
.decorated__type2 .decorated-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
.decorated .decorated-inner {
    padding: .7em 1.2em;
    position: relative;
}
.cleared {
    zoom: 1;
}
.variants {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em .7em;
}
.variants .switcher,
.variants .switcher-two,
.variants .switcher-three {
    padding: .3em 0 1em;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.variants .switcher .selected,
.variants .switcher-two .selected,
.variants .switcher-three .selected {
    background: #eaeaea;
}
.variants .switcher li,
.variants .switcher-two li,
.variants .switcher-three li {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
}
.variants .opening_view {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decorated decorated__type2">
<div class="decorated-inner cleared">

<div class="variants">
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<ul class="switcher">
<li class="for_opening_view selected" data-show="one">1</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="two">2</li>
</ul>
<div class="switch-js">
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="one">Content for 'One' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="two">Content for 'Two' data-show</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="variants">
<h3>Title 2</h3>
<ul class="switcher-two">
<li class="for_opening_view selected" data-show="three">1</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="four">2</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="five">3</li>
</ul>
<div class="switch-js-2">
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="three">Content for 'Three' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="four">Content for 'Four' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="five">Content for 'Five' data-show</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="variants">
<h3>Title 3</h3>
<ul class="switcher-three">
<li class="for_opening_view selected" data-show="six">1</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="seven">2</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="eight">3</li>
<li class="for_opening_view" data-show="nine">4</li>
</ul>
<div class="switch-js-3">
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="six">Content for 'Six' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="seven">Content for 'Seven' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="eight">Content for 'Eight' data-show</div>
<div class="opening_view" data-switch="nine">Content for 'Nine' data-show</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Да, я знаю что код скрипта ужасен, я просто пока не знаю как написать его правильно. Если кто-то покажет как правильно или пояснит, буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function switcher(){
 [].forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("[data-switcher]"),(a)=>{
  let b = a.querySelectorAll("[data-switcher-name]"),
   c = a.querySelectorAll("[data-switcher-show]");
  [].forEach.call(c,(d)=>{
   if (d.dataset.switcherSelected != undefined) {
    d.classList.add("selected");
    [].filter.call(b,(a)=>a.dataset.switcherName==d.dataset.switcherShow?a.classList.add("selected"):"");
   }
   d.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    [].forEach.call(c,(a)=>a!=d?a.classList.remove("selected"):a.classList.add("selected"));
    [].forEach.call(b,(a)=>a.dataset.switcherName!=d.dataset.switcherShow?a.classList.remove("selected"):a.classList.add("selected"));
   },true);
  });
 });
}
window.onload = function() {
 switcher();
}
```

```css
[data-switcher] {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em .7em;
}
[data-switcher-show] {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
[data-switcher-show].selected {
 background-color: #eaeaea;
}
[data-switcher-name]:not(.selected) {
 display: none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
.decorated {
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
 display: inline-block;
}
.decorated .decorated-inner {
    padding: .7em 1.2em;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="decorated">

 <div class="decorated-inner">

  <div class="variants" data-switcher>
   <h3>Title 1</h3>
   <ul class="switcher">
    <li data-switcher-show="0" data-switcher-selected>1</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="1">2</li>
   </ul>
   <div data-switcher-name="0">Content for 'One'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="1">Content for 'Two'</div>
  </div>

  <div class="variants" data-switcher>
   <h3>Title 2</h3>
   <ul class="switcher">
    <li data-switcher-show="0">1</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="1" data-switcher-selected>2</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="2">3</li>
   </ul>
   <div data-switcher-name="0">Content for 'Three'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="1">Content for 'Four'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="2">Content for 'Five'</div>
  </div>

  <div class="variants" data-switcher>
   <h3>Title 3</h3>
   <ul class="switcher">
    <li data-switcher-show="0">1</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="1">2</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="2" data-switcher-selected>3</li>
    <li data-switcher-show="3">4</li>
   </ul>
   <div data-switcher-name="0">Content for 'Six'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="1">Content for 'Seven'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="2">Content for 'Eight'</div>
   <div data-switcher-name="3">Content for 'Nine'</div>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Не подскажите как лучше реализовать скрытие лишних вариантов? То есть чтобы всегда отображался только один в зависимости от выбранного переключателя; при перезагрузке страницы всегда первые.

Comment: @Hekk0 обновил код

Comment: спасибо за замечательный код. пожалуйста подскажите как сделать так, чтобы выделение было только на активном списке. Т.е выделен только один li активный. только в одном списке - активном